# htaccess file to do specific rewrites on different uri

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Block hidden directories
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    # Prevent /health_check.php from using https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(health_check\.php)$

    # Prevent /sns from using https but this DOES need codeigniter rewriting (see below)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sns)/

    # Reroute http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Prevent rewriting of domain for codeigniter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

It all seems to be working OK except for the `/sns` part. I can't get this to stop redirecting to https.

I would like `http://sub.example.com/sns` and `http://sub.example.com/health_check.php` to not redirect to https.

Comment: Please include a complete example of the (`/sns`) URL you are trying to prevent from being redirected. Is Codeigniter itself issuing this redirect later in the request? (_Aside:_ You should remove the `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_.)

Comment: Added the complete URLs I want to prevent...

Comment: The regex in your rule includes a trailing slash, but your stated URL does not?! (Or is this a typo?)

Comment: It could be either to be honest, but it will probably be without

Comment: Can you just clarify the URL you are being redirected to? Is it `https://sub.example.com/sns` or `https://sub.example.com/index.php/sns`? Also, you've stated a subdomain. Do you have another site on the main domain? Does this other site share the same filespace?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Prevent /sns from using https but this DOES need codeigniter rewriting (see below)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sns)/
> ```

If the request URL does not end with a trailing slash (as stated), then the above rule (which includes the trailing slash on the *CondPattern*) will always be successful (it's a *negated* condition), so the redirect to HTTPS will always occur.

Ideally, you should be canonicalising the trailing slash earlier in the request. Either include the trailing slash or not (otherwise, it's essentially *duplicate content* and could potentially cause problems with other scripts that parse the URL).

However, to handle the two URLs `/sns` and `/sns/` then you need to make the trailing slash optional and include the end-of-string anchor (`^`). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sns/?$
```

Note that this only matches the two URLs stated. It will not match a URL of the form `/sns/<something>`.

I've removed the parentheses around the path segment (you should also remove other parentheses in your regex). This creates a captured group and is superfluous in the directives you have posted.

**UPDATE:** You'll also need an additional check to make sure the rewritten URL (ie. `/index.php/sns`) is not redirected. You can do this in a more general way by only applying the HTTPS redirect on the initial request, not the rewritten request, by including an additional condition:

```
# Only applies to direct requests (not rewritten requests)
RewriteCond {%ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is set to "200" after the first successful rewrite (ie. the CodeIgniter routing). It is not set on the initial request (ie. `^$` - empty string).

If this still results in a redirect then it's possible that CodeIgniter itself is triggering the redirect (after `.htaccess` has been processed).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

*Aside:* And as noted in my comment, you should remove the `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *susbtitution*. See the [end of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966041/369434) on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948712/htaccess-rewriterule-match-special-characters-in-url-path) for an explanation.

### Summary

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Block hidden directories
RewriteRule ^\. - [F]

# Only applies to direct requests (not rewritten requests)
RewriteCond {%ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

# Prevent /health_check.php from using https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !health_check\.php$

# Prevent /sns from using https but this DOES need codeigniter rewriting (see below)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sns/?$

# Reroute http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Prevent rewriting of domain for codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect, but only once you have confirmed it's working OK. The `R` flag on its own defaults to a 302 (temporary) redirect.

(You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper either, unless you site is intended to work without mod_rewrite?)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?